# I want to get the specific reviews from a different model Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am making a review section for my record company, but I have a hard time figuring out how I can get the specific reviews for the specific album, I pass in an id to a template called "Albumin" to get the exact album, but how do I get the reviews?

models:

```py
class albums(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    release_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(choices=GENRE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default2.jpg', upload_to='album_pics')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        
class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(albums, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    review = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject or f"ReviewRating #{self.pk}"
```

views:

```py
def albuminfo(request, id):
    album = albums.objects.get(id = id)
    reviews = ReviewRating.objects.all()
    return render(request, "home/AlbumInfo.html", {'album' : album, 'reviews' : reviews})
    
def submit_review(request, album_id):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            reviews = ReviewRating.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id, album__id=album_id) 
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST, instance=reviews)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Your review has been updated')
            return redirect(url)
        except ReviewRating.DoesNotExist:
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = ReviewRating()
                data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
                data.review = form.cleaned_data['review']
                data.rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
                data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                data.album_id = album_id
                data.user_id = request.user.id
                data.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Your review has been submitted')
                return redirect(url)
```

URLs:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homeview.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('albums/', views.album, name='Nartonmusic-album'),
    path('artists/', views.artists, name='Nartonmusic-artists'),
    path('albuminfo/<int:id>/', views.albuminfo, name='AlbumInfo'),
    path('submit_review/<int:album_id>/', views.submit_review, name='submit_review'),
]
```

as you can see in the code I tried to use reviews = ReviewRating.objects.all() but this of course doesn't work because this gathers ALL the reviews.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly easy for you to get the album when you have the review.

```py
rev = ReviewRating.objects.all().first()
album = rev.album
```

The other way around is called reversed lookup. With the ForeignKey relationship
One Review is related to One Album but one Album is related to multiple Reviews. Let's call it a "set of reviews" as it already leads you to the python syntax:

```py
album = Album.objects.all().first()
all_albums_reviews = album.reviewrating_set.all()
```

`all_albums_reviews` is a normal queryset. You can call all queryset methods on it like `.get()` or `.filter()` methods.

The reverse lookups are also to be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/). I agree it is a bit hidden but when you search the site for "_set" you will see more examples.

#### Ready to use view:

```py
def albuminfo(request, id):
    album = albums.objects.get(id = id)
    all_albums_reviews = album.reviewrating_set.all()
    return render(request, "home/AlbumInfo.html", {'album' : album, 'reviews' : all_albums_reviews})
```